# Как сделать след от нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: java, android

Не пойму как сделать вот такой след у кнопки, который заполняется при нажатии на него. Может кто знает как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте вот это добавить для нужных элементов в разметку: `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: Во-первых, что значит знак вопроса? Во-вторых, если я поменяю background, то соответственно слетит картинка плея.

Comment: `?` - это указание на то, что надо взять значение из текущей темы, т.е. значение может быть разным для светлой/тёмной темы и взято будет в этих случаях разное. Картинку надо не в виде фона устанавливать. Если у вас `ImageView` - используйте `android:src` для картинки.

Comment: В общем, решил использовать FloatingActionButton. Но возникли 2 проблемы. Фото в вопросе. Если кнопка нажата, то появляется у нее тень, хоть elevation стоит на 0. И второй, как можно настроить положение картинки, а то она ставиться как-то криво.

Comment: FAB очень плохо настраивается. Используйте `ImageView` с фоном и картинкой - это точно будет работать и настроить можно всё что угодно. FAB тут не годится, она для другого.

Comment: Хорошо было бы если он не дорисовывал еще один круг.  Можно от этого избавиться? И как все таки настроить положение самой картинки?

Comment: У вас не получится изменить FAB. Да это и не нужно и вообще не правильно. Я же вам предложил уже единственно работающий и самый простой вариант - почему вы не хотите его использовать?

Comment: Дак я и использовал ImageView, добавил ваш задник и вставил картинку через  scr. Но картинка плохо встает и анимация заполнения двойная. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Иконку можно исправить если её иначе вписать в квадрат. Сейчас она у вас не по середине своего квадрата. Анимацию двойную, вроде, никак не отменить и надо городить свою. Не думаю, что вам стоит тратить на это время)

Answer (score -1):

New->Android XML File (Drawable, selector) c названием например  "icon_phone"
туды вот это:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

создаешь два файла в ресурсах drawable:
drawable/button_normal - суда изображение не нажатой, 
drawable/button_pressed - суда изображение нажатой (со следом)

в свойствах кнопки:

```
android:drawable="@drawable/icon_phone"
```

Comment: Дак дело-то не в изменениях картинок нажатой и не нажатой кнопки. Открой вк и там в плеере это реализовано. Там по нажатии оно само заполняется в виде окружности.

Comment: надо корректнее формулировать вопрос, ссылкой на вк, например. вк не пользуюсь, извините не узнал по внешнему виду.

Comment: Простите, не привык задавать банальные вопросы)